# Scatter google chart - string values in Y axis

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Since yesterday i try to draw chart with google charts. I have one problem. I tried to put strings on Y-axis, and script doesn't display anything.

I tried to do this with code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['scatter']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart () {

var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('number', 'document');
data.addColumn('string', 'term');

data.addRows([
         [1 , 'word1'] , [3 , 'word2']
]);
var options = {
    width: 900,
    height: 500,
    chart: {
        title: 'weight of terms'
    },
    axes: {
        x: {
              0: {side: 'bottom'}
          } 
         }
    };

var chart = new google.charts.Scatter(document.getElementById('scatter_top_x'));


chart.draw(data, google.charts.Scatter.convertOptions(options));
}
</script>
```

That gives me a result: http://darium.linuxpl.eu/chart/

The goal: I wanna draw sometnig like this-

https://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2015/08/25/asd.png

Is there any way to draw what I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string

So you need to change the axis,

```js
google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['scatter']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart () {

var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
 data.addColumn('string', 'term');
    data.addColumn('number', 'document');

 data.addRows([
         ['word1', 1] , ['word2', 3]
 ]);
    
var options = {
    width: 900,
    height: 500,
    chart: {
        title: 'weight of terms'
    },
    axes: {
        x: {
              0: {side: 'bottom'}
          } 
         }
    };

var chart = new google.charts.Scatter(document.getElementById('scatter_top_x'));

chart.draw(data, google.charts.Scatter.convertOptions(options));
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="scatter_top_x"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's so helpful

Comment: welcome, please accept as an answer if you satisfied.